# Javascript: Return a variable after firing a function for use

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

*Forgive me if this is a very basic question, but I'm hoping someone here can explain it very clearly for a beginner to JS.*

I noticed that I've used the same code in two places and therefore made a function to fire. But I want to use a variable that I created in this function to use after it's been completed. Here's a code example:

```
function calculate_animation(direction) {
    var theWidth = parseInt(visibleArea.outerWidth() - 70),
        currentMargin = parseInt(listingsSlider.css('margin-left')),
        hoursVisible = Math.floor(theWidth / itemWidth),
        hoursWidth = itemWidth * hoursVisible,
        newMargin = currentMargin - hoursWidth;
}


forwardBtn.click(function () {
    calculate_animation();

    // animate the slider
    listingsSlider.animate({
        'margin-left': newMargin + 'px'
    });
});
```

So I created a new variable called `newMargin` in the `calculate_animation` function, and I'm trying to use it in the animate function below.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a scope issue. The newMargin variable is defined inside the function and so the scope of the variable begins at the beginning of the function where it defined with `var` keyword and ends at the end of the function.

You can use `return newMargin` to return the calculated value back to the caller.

See below,

```
function calculate_animation(direction) {
        var theWidth        =  parseInt(visibleArea.outerWidth() - 70),
            currentMargin   = parseInt(listingsSlider.css('margin-left')),
            hoursVisible    = Math.floor(theWidth / itemWidth),
            hoursWidth    = itemWidth * hoursVisible,
            newMargin       =  currentMargin - hoursWidth;

        return newMargin;
}


forwardBtn.click(function () {
        // animate the slider
        listingsSlider.animate({'margin-left' : calculate_animation() + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could put the function name `calculate_animation()` in place of a variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `return` keyword in your function...

```
function calculate_animation(direction) {
        var theWidth        =  parseInt(visibleArea.outerWidth() - 70),
            currentMargin   = parseInt(listingsSlider.css('margin-left')),
            hoursVisible    = Math.floor(theWidth / itemWidth),
            hoursWidth    = itemWidth * hoursVisible,
            newMargin       =  currentMargin - hoursWidth;

        return newMargin;
}


forwardBtn.click(function () {
        var newMargin = calculate_animation();

        // animate the slider
        listingsSlider.animate({'margin-left' : newMargin + 'px'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return it to the function which is called and use that variable in the called function..

```
function calculate_animation(direction) {
    var theWidth = parseInt(visibleArea.outerWidth() - 70),
        currentMargin = parseInt(listingsSlider.css('margin-left')),
        hoursVisible = Math.floor(theWidth / itemWidth),
        hoursWidth = itemWidth * hoursVisible,
        newMargin = currentMargin - hoursWidth;
    return newMargin;
}


forwardBtn.click(function () {
    var newMargin = calculate_animation();

    // animate the slider
    listingsSlider.animate({
        'margin-left': newMargin + 'px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `return` it: (What's the direction parameter for? You aren't using it anywhere)

```
function calculate_animation(direction) {
        var theWidth        =  parseInt(visibleArea.outerWidth() - 70),
            currentMargin   = parseInt(listingsSlider.css('margin-left')),
            hoursVisible    = Math.floor(theWidth / itemWidth),
            hoursWidth    = itemWidth * hoursVisible,
            newMargin       =  currentMargin - hoursWidth;

        return newMargin;
}


forwardBtn.click(function () {
        var newMargin = calculate_animation();

        // animate the slider
        listingsSlider.animate({'margin-left' : newMargin + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: I'll be using direction later for something else. Thanks for spotting though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can return from that function, instead you declare the variable globally and change its value whenever required.